# Guava to Java 8 conversion

Tags: java-8, guava

I'm migrating my Guava Functions and Predicates to Java 8.  Unparameterized Predictates are easy, I just change from class to interface and put a "default" in front of the apply() method.  What I'm stuck on is parameterized Predicates.  How can I define a reusable parameterized predicate in Java 8.  Here's my current Guava code:

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate

public class InSectorPredicate implements Predicate<Unit> {
    private final SectorCoords coords;

    public InSectorPredicate(SectorCoords coords) {
        this.coords = coords;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean apply(Unit unit) {
        return unit.getCoords().equals(coords);
    }
}
```

Comment: “*I just change from class to interface and put a "default" in front of the apply() method*”—why on Earth are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Changing `apply` to `test` doesn't work?

and obviously replace `import com.google.common.base.Predicate;` with `import java.util.function.Predicate;`

Comment: Interfaces can't maintain state.  The issue is the coords parameter.

Comment: Umm, yes but `InSectorPredicate8` is a class, also please listen to @Holger comments about putting "default" in front of the apply() .

Answer (score 1):

> Interfaces can't maintain state. The issue is the coords parameter.

But it doesn't need to be an interface? you can simply use a class like you already have been. Or hell, while you are in a migration state, just continue to use the Guava Predicates as the type signature of Guava's Predicate is

`public interface Predicate<T> extends java.util.function.Predicate<T>` So they will continue to work on Java 8

From the JD of Guava's Predicate:

```
  * <p>As this interface extends {@code java.util.function.Predicate}, an instance of this type may  
  * be used as a {@code Predicate} directly.  To use a {@code java.util.function.Predicate} where a  
  * {@code com.google.common.base.Predicate} is expected, use the method reference {@code  
  * predicate::test}.
```

Example code, if you want to port.

```
public class InSectorPredicate8 implements java.util.function.Predicate<Unit> {
    private final SectorCoords coords;

    public InSectorPredicate8(SectorCoords coords) {
        this.coords = coords;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(Unit unit) {
        return unit.getCoords().equals(coords);
    }
}
```

But depending on exact usage, most of the time where you would construct the InSectorPredicate, you could simply, do

```
Predicate<Unit> InSectorPredicate = new InSectorPredicate(coords);
```

migrates to

```
Predicate<Unit> InSectorPredicate = (Unit unit) -> unit.getCoords().equals(coords);
```

Comment: Or even shorter `Predicate<Unit> InSectorPredicate = unit -> unit.getCoords().equals(coords);`